# Openpyxl AttributeError

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I was running this file fine yesterday and now I'm getting an `AttributeError` when I tried running it today. Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook           

def read_in():
    wb = load_workbook('GenerateModel.xlsx')
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    da_name = []
    for i in range(1, ws.max_row+1):
         if ws.cell(row=i,column=3).value != None and (
         ws.cell(row=i,column=3).value != u'DA Name'):
         da_name.append(ws.cell(row=i,column=3).value.encode('ascii'))


     start_date = ws.cell(row=4, column=4).value
     end_date = ws.cell(row=4, column=5).value

     if start_date == None or end_date == None:
         raise ValueError('Date cannot be left blank')

     if start_date > end_date:
         raise ValueError('Start Date must be less than End Date')
```

And here is the error that I get:

```
line 28, in read_in
for i in range(1, ws.max_row+1):

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'max_row'
```

I tried running another python script and I'm getting an ImportError that says

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
ImportError: cannot import name PatternFill
```

This makes me think that there is something wrong with the `openpyxl` module. I installed it using pip and I'm using the Spyder IDE. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What if you do the `print(openpyxl.__version__)`  before reading the workbook? What version does it output?

Comment: It says '1.8.5'

Comment: Yeah, it's very old - hence the absence of `max_row` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It says '1.8.5'

Your `openpyxl` version is *seriously outdated* - hence the absence of `max_row` attribute on a `WorkSheet` class.

You need to figure out what Python executable is used when you run your script from the Spyder IDE and then update `openpyxl` in that environment:

```
pip install --upgrade openpyxl
```

(currently latest `openpyxl` is `2.4.8`)